# HTML ignoring php tags and print plain text issue

Tags: php, html

Hi in a HTML document I'm including some some inside one of the divs, however it just prints the php code as plain text and kind of ignores the php tags. here is how I code it.

```
    </form>        //just some html tags right before the php tags
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p id="hint"></p>

<?php                 // the begining of the php tags
form();
function form(){
    print "<form method='post' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>";
    print"<input type='text' name='species'/>"; 
    print"<input type='submit' name='submit'/>"; 
    print"</form>";

}

echo '<div id='language_information'>';
?>

  </div>
  <div style ="display:none;"id="about" title="How it works">'
```

Here is what the inspect element in chrome gives me, just commented and plain text

```
  <p id="hint"></p>
      <!--?php
form();
function form(){
    print "<form method='post' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'-->

      ";
    print"
    <input type="text" name="species"></input>
      "; 
    print"
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
```

Comment: What is the extensions of your file ? Does your host allows php ?

Comment: Yes, make sure your host and/or server allows PHP.  Then, make sure that your file has a .php extension, or that your host/server is configured to parse PHP in file with whatever extension you are using (e.g. ".html").

Comment: @DarkBee yes my host allows PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure document extension should be `.php` not `.html`.

In most servers only files with `.php` extensions are parsed, so if you use any PHP in your HTML file its extension should be `.php`

Comment: but it is a html doc, I just use the php tags once as a wrapper for a form

Comment: @Squirtle, does not matter. Standard server config only parse PHP in .php files

Answer (score 2):

You said that you have saved the file as HTML document. Thats the problem.

```
Please note that the server interprets HTML and PHP files differently.
```

HTML files are sent directly to browser whereas PHP files are not. So when your file is saved as HTML,it is sent to browser directly,which cannot parse the PHP code and hence the output.

Its to best to re-save your file as PHP doc.

Also,for future reference please note that even in a PHP file,order of parsing is

1. PHP
2. HTML,CSS,Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The code and output don't match up as the delimiter `-->` isn't in the source.

Lastly, it doesn't look like this is being run from a PHP-enabled server - at the least the PHP isn't be executed. Try fixing the file extension or testing it in a local server like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) and see if you can replicate the error.

Comment: @devsheeep I've never seen `print` used before, but I stand totally corrected.

Answer (score 0):

are you running the page through a webserver like XAMPP that supports PHP, or did you simply double click the page and open it in your favourite browser from the explorer window?

If you are trying to get the page to work with PHP, you need to put it in the correct folder (which for example might be xampp/htdocs) and then navigate to `http://localhost` in your browser

Also depending on your configuration the server may not parse the PHP code in HTML files and may only execute PHP files instead. I think by default many "less serious" webservers such as XAMPP, LAMP etc will parse pretty much anything thrown at them by default, so file naming shouldn't be an issue.